# Install RHEL 5.7S on machine with 4TB disks

Tags: rhel, system-installation, bios, kickstart, raid5

I'm getting errors about GPT when installing OS using kickstart.

The Dell R720 has 8x 600GB SAS.  I can't figure out what to configure in BIOS and kickstart file.

In BIOS, there're boot options of BIOS and UEFI.  SATA has a few options, AHCI and RAID mode.  In PERC, I select all disks and select RAID level 5.

I tried a few combinations but they all don't work.  Does anyone here has experience setting up machine with such large local disk array?

My kickstart.cfg has this:

```
clearpart --all --drives=sda
part /boot --fstype ext3 --size=16
part pv.2 --size=0 --grow --ondisk=sda
volgroup vg --pesize=65536 pv.2

logvol / --fstype ext3 --name=root --vgname=vg --size=51200
logvol swap --fstype swap --name=swp --vgname=vg --size=131072
logvol /tmp --fstype ext3 --name=tmp --vgname=vg --size=524288
logvol /opt/lo --fstype ext3 --name=lo --vgname=vg --size=3072000
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will probably want BIOS over UEFI for RHEL5. The SAS is from an expansion slot or on the mainboard?

Comment: the configuration of RAID5 is a bit tricky on the Dell machine but after that it should be really easy, excet if your disk manager is not supported by the RHEL your trying to install

Answer (score 1):

I found this article that discusses the setup under CentOS 6 but much of it should still apply. The article's titled: [Forcing GUID Partition Table on a disk with CentOS 6](http://bodgitandscarper.co.uk/centos/forcing-guid-partition-table-on-a-disk-with-centos-6/).

In your kickstart file you'll need to do this in your `%pre` section:

```
%pre
/usr/sbin/parted -s /dev/sda mklabel gpt
%end
```

And then make sure that you do not include any `clearpart`, let the installation default to using the "whole disk".

*excerpt*

> Then make sure your kickstart contains no clearpart instructions so it
>   will default to just using the empty space. The only small nit I found
>   after the install is that the minimal install option only includes
>   fdisk and not parted as well so if you want to manage the disk
>   partitions you’ll need to add that either at install time or
>   afterwards as fdisk doesn’t support GPT.

I believe you might have to "return to the installer" by giving the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.

Comment: Cent6 = RHEL6. RHEL5 will most likely lack some of the support RHEL6 does.

Comment: @Tim - agreed, but there isn't a ton of changes going into kickstart & anaconda so what I suggested will likely be the same.